# Scala: Elegant solution to iterate over (List, List)

Tags: scala

I'm trying to come up with an "elegant" solution to iterate over two lists (pairs of values), and perform some tests on the resulting values.

Any ideas? Here's what I have so far, but I get "value filter is not a member of (List[Int], List[Int])," which surprises me I thought this would work. AND, I feel like there must be a much cleaner way to express this in Scala.

```
val accounts = random(count = 100, minimum = 1, maximum = GPDataTypes.integer._2)
val ids = random(count = 100, minimum = 1, maximum = GPDataTypes.integer._2)

for ((id, accountId) <- (ids, accounts)) {
  val g = new GPGlimple(Some(id), Some(timestamp), accountId, false, false, 2)
  println(g)
  g.accountId mustEqual accountId
  g.id mustEqual id
  g.created.get must beLessThan(System.currentTimeMillis)
  g.layers must beNone
  g.version must be equalTo 2
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest solution for this is [`zip`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.5/index.html#scala.collection.immutable.List@zip[B]%28that:scala.collection.GenIterable[B]%29:List[%28A,B%29]):

```
(ids zip accounts)
```

The documentation for `zip` says:

> Returns a list formed from this list and another iterable collection by combining corresponding elements in pairs.

In other words, `zip` will return a list of tuples.

The `zipped` method could also work here:

```
(ids, accounts).zipped
```

You can find the `zipped` source for 2-tuples [`here`](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.11.5/src/library/scala/runtime/Tuple2Zipped.scala#L1).  Note that this is made available through an enrichment of `(T, U)` where `T` is implicitly viewable as a `TraversableLike` and `U` is implicitly viewable as an `IterableLike`.  That method returns a `ZippedTraversable2`, which is a minimal interface that encapsulates this sort of zipped return, and behaves more efficiently for large sequences by inhibiting the creation of intermediary collections.  These are generally more performant because they use `iterators` internally, as can be seen in the source.

Note that the returns here are of different types, which could affect downstream behavior.  One important difference is that the normal combinator methods on `ZippedTraversable2` are slightly different that those on a `Traversable` of tuples.  The methods on `ZippedTraversable2` generally expect a function of 2 arguments, while those on a `Traversable` of tuples will expect a function with a single argument that is a tuple.  For example, you can check this in the REPL for the `foreach` method:

```
val s1 = List(1, 2, 3)
val s2 = List('a', 'b', 'c')

(s1 -> s2).zipped.foreach _
// ((Int, Char) => Any) => Unit = <function1>
(s1 zip s2).foreach _
// (((Int, Char)) => Any) => Unit = <function1> 
//Notice the extra parens here, signifying a method with a tuple argument
```

This difference means that you sometimes have to use a different syntax when using `zip` and `zipped`:

```
(s1 zip s2).map { x => x._1 + x._2 }
(s1, s2).zipped.map { x => x._1 + x._2 } //This won't work!  The method shouldn't expect a tuple argument

//conversely
(s1, s2).zipped.map { (x, y) => x + y }
(s1 zip s2).map { (x, y) => x + y } //This won't work!  The method shouldn't expect 2 arguments

//Added note: methods with 2 arguments can often use the more concise underscore notation:
(s1, s2).zipped.map { _ + _ }
```

Note that if you use the `case` notation, you're covered either way:

```
//case works for both syntaxes
(s1, s2).zipped.map { case (x, y) => x + y } \
(s1 zip s2).map { case (x, y) => x + y }
```

This works since the compiler understands this notation for methods with either two arguments, or a single tuple argument, as explained in [section 8.5 of the spec](http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/08-pattern-matching.html#pattern-matching-anonymous-functions):

```
val f: (Int, Int) => Int = { case (a, b) => a + b }
val g: ((Int, Int)) => Int = { case (a, b) => a + b }
```

Comment: It'd be useful to explain how these are different.

Comment: I don't think that `zipped` would work as presented here. `map` on the result of `zipped` accepts a function of two arguments, not a function of a single argument, so pattern matching won't work.

Comment: @TravisBrown I've added details explaining the difference.  Let me know if you think I've missed anything.

Comment: @VladimirMatveev The case syntax works either way – I've added a note to the answer

Answer (score 1):

Use [zip](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.5/index.html#scala.collection.immutable.List@zip[B](that:scala.collection.GenIterable[B]):List[(A,B)]):

```
for ((id, accountId) <- ids.zip(accounts)) {
   // ...     
}
```